# Common approch to edit UITableViewCell in new View

Tags: ios, ios5

I would like to implement some kind of standard way to edit a cell value. The idea is to make it work like the settings on iphone where after you click on the value you get to new view and edit it according to the type.

One approach could be to handle the "click" of the cells and open a modal view:

```
(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

But I dont know if there a common/good way how to handle this edits using a generic view to edit fields according to the "type" (text, multiple choice, date, etc)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically if you want to edit a field you should push a new view on rather than present it modally. Unfortunately you will have to implement the editing view to be pushed on.